# Linking portaudio into a C program on Linux

Tags: c, linux, portaudio

Problem with  linking portaudio into an c program on Linux.
System: Linux Ubuntu 20.4 i5 16 GB
ALSA and pulseaudio were preinstralled.
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

gcc -Wall wm_1.c -lm libportaudio.a -o wm_1
The linker gives me more than 100 error messages all of type "undefined reference"
Here 2  examples out of >100
/home/max/Desktop/dev/portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:504: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status_get_delay' /home/max/Desktop/dev/portaudio/src/hostapi/oss/pa_unix_oss.c:1778: undefined reference to` __pthread_unregister_cancel'
So its obvious that the named parameter/function can not be found.

The error messages all point to source files in the source directory (the directory of the portaudio
package I downloaded to creatie the libs which were all created without error.
The libs are in /usr/local/..
libportaudio.a  libportaudio.la  libportaudio.so  libportaudio.so.2  libportaudio.so.2.0.0  pkgconfig  python3.8
and I copied libportaudio.a into the project directory.  The lib has a a size of 1.1 MB .

if I use the dynamic libportaudio.so  I get the error messages at run time.

I suspect that something went totally wrong with creating the libraries but I have no idea how to solve that
Other option:
Linking parameter or files missing ?
Header file ?

The same program compiles, links and runs without any problem on a  iMac OS 10.13.6
where I used the dynamic lib  .dylib.
gcc -v wm_1.c libportaudio.dylib -o wm_1

Comment: Have you tried adding `-pthread` when compiling/lnking? `gcc -Wall -pthread wm_1.c -lm libportaudio.a -o wm_1`

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html):

> Note that you will usually need to link with the approriate libraries that you used, such as ALSA and JACK, as well as with librt and libpthread. For example:
>
> gcc main.c libportaudio.a -lrt -lm -lasound -ljack -pthread -o YOUR_BINARY

A little googling goes a long way...

Answer (score 0):

This works:
gcc -Wall wm_1.c -lm libportaudio.a -lasound  -pthread -o test.

gcc main.c libportaudio.a -lrt -lm -lasound -ljack -pthread -o YOUR_BINARY
I used that page and the command line at the begin using all 3 parameter but got errors, probably of misspelling, so I gave up on that (also because on the Mac OS it was not necessary).  It now links without errors using -lasound and -pthread only (-pthread alone gives still errors and  the use/not use of -ljack makes no difference).
I get some errors when I run the program but  probably because of missing or wrong ALSA parameter settings. I found -pthread but I could not find -ljack and -lasound.

So the question: what are this 2 parameter doing?
It must be link parameter, but where is the documentation, I searched  ld and gcc and did not find anything, while -pthread is documented.